# Check for redundancy before downloading any file

Tags: files, mp3, download-manager, md5sum, checksums

Is there a way you can check whether you have already downloaded a file previously or not before actually downloading it.

**I know** -

- [wget](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119023/wget-duplicate-files) can do that, only if the filename of the file trying to be fetched is same as compared to the file already retrieved before.
- You can apply [checksum or md5hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_duplicate_file_finders) for finding & removing redundant files, but this can be done only AFTER you have downloaded the file.

Please suggest a way to check whether a file is same in terms of content before actually downloading it FULLY again (independent of the filename its gonna save into).

**To make it more precise**: I am interested in downloading ONLY **mp3** files but from different sources like Jamendo, Soundcloud etc. which may have same content(song) but will be having different filenames.

Comment: Is the source providing any detail? Fingerprints? Checksums?

Comment: one can access metadata of the mp3s on both soundcloud and jamendo, which obviously may be different for file from different sources. But can't find any checksum.

Comment: If the different sources for the same song have different bit rates and/or track length, then it might pose a problem...

Comment: @Rohith, assuming, the "uploader" has uploaded the exact same files on both the servers, but different filenames say file_soundcloud.mp3, file_jamendo.mp3. Then, is it possible ?

Comment: I am not sure whether you'll be able to determine whether the file contents exactly match before downloading the file.

Answer (score 2):

Read the first 500 bytes of the first file:

`head -c 500 file1.mp3 > fragment1`

Use `curl -r 0-499 -o fragment2 http://...` to retrieve the first 500 bytes of the second file. Then, do `diff fragment1 fragment2` to see if they are equal.

[`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) is a tool like `wget` only with more options. The `-r` flag lets you specify a range, which will result in a partial download. `wget` has a quota option that will not, however, let you do a partial download.

Comment: My bad, it looked like a clever answer and I considered upvoting it, but I suspected metadata to be present in the very first section of the file. I didn't read the [source](http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm) well, and metadata are actually in the very *last* 128 bytes. So +1

Comment: @kos [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2) says you were right the first time - I also thought ID3 tags occurred at the end of the file. I now see that ID3v2 tags are placed at the start. And as one of the tags may be artwork of unpredictable size, there is no certain way of bypassing these. Thanks for upvoting anyway.

Comment: Well the source I read is actually outdated (ID3 v1). Then if N is the size of the file, maybe reading bytes from N-628 to N-128?

Comment: @kos That would work, but I suspect that then `curl` will download most of the file and simply discard the first N-628 bytes, defeating the purpose. I wonder if [Tunatic](http://wildbits.com/tunatic) still works?

Comment: Nope looks like it downloads only the required section, I tried with `curl -r 1000000000-1000000500 -o fragment2 http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso
`, it just worked fine

Comment: @kos Thanks (you downloaded 1 byte too many, but hey). I'll revise my answer.

Comment: Anyway, comparing files that have tags built in will only work if the tags are of exactly equal length. Given that, the files have a high probability of being equal anyway. So I guess that my answer is still somewhat useful. To bypass tags altogether, one would have to write a program using one of the ID3 libraries. I suppose that is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: ID3v1 and ID3v1.1 tags have always 128 bytes reserved no matter what the tag length is, so the very last 128 bytes are always used. I added another answer to check this using a bash script

Answer (score 1):

Based on Jos' answer, here's a `bash` script that will compare the two files from byte `<file_size>-628` to byte `<file_size>-129` (latest 500 Bytes before `ID3v1` and `ID3v1.1` tags), excluding `ID3v1` and `ID3v1.1` tags from the comparison. Copy the script's code and paste it into a text file named `script.sh` (or whatever) and in a `Terminal` run `chmod a+x <script_path>` to mark it as executable:

(Note: the script only works if `curl` is able to determine the file size)

> Usage: <script_path>/script.sh <file_path> <url>

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

size1=$(du -b "$1" | sed 's/\(.*\)\t/\1/' | tr -cd '[[:digit:]]')
size2=$(curl -I "$2" | grep -i 'content-length' | tr -cd '[[:digit:]]')
dd if="$1" of=partial1 bs=1 skip=$(($size1 - 628)) count=500
curl -r $(($size2 - 628))-$(($size2 - 129)) -o partial2 "$2"
cmp partial1 partial2
rm partial1 partial2
```